# How to download attachments from gmail using api

Tags: php, cakephp, gmail, imap

I have tried IMAP solution mentioned here.

[download gmail attachements from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395422/download-gmail-attachements-from-php)

I am using cakephp. It times out after 60 seconds.

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'david***@gmail.com';
$password = '*********';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to post the code you've tried or give more details regarding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to refer you to [Mail](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html) component from Apache Zeta Components. I waas just toying with it the other day and both sending and retrieving attachments from Gmail was really easy (just follow tutorials)

AN example code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('classes/zeta/Base/src/ezc_bootstrap.php');

spl_autoload_register( array( 'ezcBase', 'autoload' ) );

$options = new ezcMailImapTransportOptions();
$options->ssl = true;

$imap = new ezcMailImapTransport("imap.gmail.com",993,$options);

$imap->authenticate("user@gmail.com","password");
$mailboxes = $imap->listMailboxes();

$imap->selectMailbox('[Gmail]/All Mail');

$set = $imap->fetchAll();

$parser = new ezcMailParser();

$mail = $parser->parseMail( $set );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $mail ); $i++ )
{

    // Process $mail[$i] such as use $mail[$i]->subject, $mail[$i]->body
    echo "From: {$mail[$i]->from}, Subject: {$mail[$i]->subject}\n";
    // Save the attachments to another folder
    $parts = $mail[$i]->fetchParts();
    foreach ( $parts as $part )
    {
        if ( $part instanceof ezcMailFile )
        {
            rename( $part->fileName, __DIR__ . '/' . basename( $part->contentDisposition->displayFileName ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try my ImapLib.
Worked for me with pdf attachments:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Lib/ImapLib.php

basically I use it like this inside my model:

```
    $code = 'privat';
    $account = Configure::read('Mailbox.'.$code);
    if (!$account) {
        trigger_error('Credentials missing for '.$code);
        return array();
    }

    App::import('Lib', 'Tools.ImapLib');
    $Imap = new ImapLib();
    $Imap->set('service', 'pop3');
    $res = $Imap->connect($account['address'], $account['password'], Configure::read('Mailbox.host'));
    if (!$res) {
        return array();
    }
    $messages = $Imap->msgList();
    return $messages;
```